# Scaling Identity service in multiple regions

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, cloud, scalability

We have User Database which is used for Creating/Updating users and for Identifying (reading) them. We read more often than we write. Write say around 1 million/day and read around 100+ million. We can separate read and write, but AFAIK we need strong consistency.

If we start reading from read replicas, it will be eventually consistent. There could be scenarios when user got created but is not available in read replica yet. Or, user has updated some information (name) and this change is not yet present in other regions.Serving only from one region would mean higher latency for other regions.

We are currently using RDBMS. [Netflix's Active-Active blog](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/active-active-for-multi-regional-resiliency-c47719f6685b) was a good read. But it would be a big-big change. Most importantly it would need change in mindset of Team/Organization. Also, it would take lots of effort to get it right. We need to have something in place immediately as the slow responses are troubling the business. Thus, I am trying to explore other options which can may be give us breathing space and time to think of actual implementation.

As a first step, I am planning to have a first level cache with low TTL in different regions. This will reduce quite a lot of reads. This again would be eventually consistent.

Second step could be to have cache invalidation in place. This could reduce inconsistencies a bit. This again would be eventually consistent.

- What other options are there?
- How companies like Google, Facebook etc.
  scale?
- I do not want to get into sharding. Or, should I? We do have
  auto-increments.
- Is eventual consistency really such a big pain? I
  have experience with it in a read oriented scenario but this one is
  read/write.

**[EDIT]** - Based on comments/suggestions

Here I am talking about different AWS regions. As we have single write system (1 RDBMS), all writes will come to one region only. But for implementing multi-region reads, even with async replication via db or custom (say SNS + SQS or Dynamodb streams) there could be delay because calls will cross region boundaries. There could be failures due to network issues which can again account for further delay (retries etc.).

Yes, eventual consistency will help but then we will have to account for problems listed above. We may have to accept few inconsistencies and failures. May be handle customer issues via support at times. I also, believe that these issues will be fairly less in comparison to the benefits and most of the times these issues will be temporary. What I am trying to find out is a better and simpler solution, if any. I think this is a problem which many of us would be trying to solve or many would have already solved. Thus, better to take guidance and learn.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Good problem to solve Anuj :)

Comment: are u NOT ok with eventual consistency ? Because everywhere that leads to scale.. if we try to update all nodes synchronously it is not easy to scale

Comment: I am not against eventually consistency. See edits

Answer (score 0):

I feel your solution (have read replicas across regions and have first level in-memory cache with low ttl ) is appropriate. Serve the customer from your in-memory cache. If user object is not there in this cache get it from read replica --> store in cache --> serve it. If user changes suppose name; just update your in-memory cache and create asynchronus event ( probably by sending a JMS message) to update master db.

Because u are serving from in-memory user will see updated info.

Note that this solution is perfect because this is for IAM and not for something like products information because user will be logged on from a single location at a time.

Comment: yes in second phase we may do that. I have updated the question with more details. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: I extended the design and have solved this problem with strong consistency and low 2 digit ms latency for TP 95. I will share info soon.